# Simultaneous SOAP Requests with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

We have test-plan like below:

```
Test Plan
    Thread Group 
        SOAP/XML-RPC Request 1
        SOAP/XML-RPC Request 2
        SOAP/XML-RPC Request 3
```

We have an issue when our service goes down on a certain day with a large load. We want to load test requests/responses per second, ranging from 500 to 10,000 requests over 20 mins to 1 hour.

Setting the thread value to 1200 for example only gives us roughly 60 per second. Any help to get this value up would be great folks.

Answer (score 0):

> ranging from 500 to 10,000 requests over 20 mins to 1 hour.

Do you mean 500 to 10,000 requests per second, or for example 10,000 requests over 30 mins which are a little over 5 requests på second?

I you are starting 1200 threads and not getting more than 60 requests per second it is probably not JMeter limiting the throughput. If you are sure the system can manage a higher troughput (thus it is not a service hardware problem) then I would check the network capacity between the load generating server and the service for bottlenecks.

Comment: We want to have 12000 requests per second, for 20mins, or 30mins. No bother necks from what we can see, where using 4 machines in 4 world wide location to create the load to a Blade Server that runs VMs.